# TTTAttributedLabel's touchesBegan does not get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, tttattributedlabel

everyone.

I'm been using TTTAttributedLabel on my iOS app, and I use addLinkToURL:withRange: method. But, sometimes, TTTAttributedLabel's touchesBegan does not get called.

Here is my code. This code outwardly work fine. However, sometimes, TTTAttributedLabel's delegate method is not called. So, I check the cause of failure, and I found that TTTAttributedLabel's touchesBegan sometimes does not get called. When the upper part of the label is tapped, touchesBegan get called. But, when the bottom part of the label is tapped, it is not called.

I don't know why...

Please help me...

This is cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. The messageLabel is an instance of TTTAttributedLabel.

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell = (MMTweetCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TweetCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MMTweetCells" bundle:nil];
        NSArray* array = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
        cell = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.messageLabel.delegate = self;
    cell.messageLabel.text = self.item.message;
    cell.messageLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
    for (NSDictionary* dic in self.linkArray) {
        [cell.messageLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dic[@"url"]] withRange:[dic[@"range"] rangeValue]];
    }
    [cell.messageLabel sizeToFit];
    return cell;
}
```

heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    height = margin;
    if (self.item && self.item.message) {
        UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MMTweetCells" bundle:nil];
        NSArray* array = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
        MMTweetCell* cell = (MMTweetCell *)[array objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.messageLabel.text = self.item.message;
        [cell.messageLabel sizeToFit];
        height += cell.messageLabel.frame.size.height;
    }
    return height;
}
```

Thanks.